Gmail api permissions issue - Unable to pull emails from non workspace email
We are using the Gmail API to pull emails. Right now I'm able to get the api working with my company (workspace) email and is able to successfully pull all its emails. However when I try with a personal email, it's unable to pull and throws the following error:
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: 
Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', 
{'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access 
tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'})

I assumed it was a permissions issue so I checked the permissions for the project in IAM & Admin and also the permissions inside Service Account. I made them both the same, but still, only the company email is being pulled without errors.
I spent all day trying to figure out the issue but couldn't think of anything else besides permissions.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?



Be careful, you are reading the permission in the wrong way.Granting an email on a project does not allow to pull the email from your account! In your case, it means your personal email account has owner access to the project, no more! That being said, your service account should have a domain wide delegation to grant it permission to access to your org/workspace account, i.e. all your corporate emails

And for public email, you can't have domain wide delegation (domain = gmail.com), at least as long as you are not the Google CEO!! ;)

@guillaumeblaquiere thank you so much for explaining. That makes sense now! I'm assuming the only way for users to pull their personal emails will have to be through OAuth?

Yes, you must identify yourself (or your program) as the user to access the GMAIL account

Ah understood, thank you!
